# Fetching Active IVR Call Count at Amazon Connect Contact Flow

Tags: amazon-web-services, ivr, amazon-connect

**Amazon Connect**

How can we fetch `Active IVR Call Count` at `Amazon Connect Contact Flow`?

PS: Need to fetch IVR call count, not the queue in call count.

Tried to explore using Cloudwatch, but no API to fetch Concurrent call at IVR.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible without tracking it yourself. Maybe check the CloudWatch insights to see if there something there, but nothing comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

Bigger question is where do you identify when your "IVR" starts. Where ever your starting point is for you calls, set one or more attributes, and then use your Lambda invoke as a counter to report the data where you need it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You won’t find such metric in the api, because Amazon connect counts “contacts”, not “calls”. So same call bounced between agents or having multiple agents in a conference will count more than once.

One possible solution is to listen to contact event stream and constantly updating a call count in a database. Roughly, count all inbound/outbound call events, and subtract all termination events.